# Sorting a list of dates (desc) using datetime or utc millis

Tags: java, sorting, jodatime, utc

I have a list of objects that have as a member a iso 8601 UTC string.
I would like to sort the list in descending order.
The following works:

```
Collections.sort(myList, (o1, o2) -> { o2.getDate().compare(o1.getDate()) } );
```

the function `getDate()` is implemented as follows:

```
public DateTime getDate() {
        return new DateTime(isoUtcString);
}
```

I am not sure if instantiating the `DateTime` each time is the best way. Also I know I could use `millis` as well. Eg. I could have

```
long utcMillis = new DateTime(isoUtcString).getMillis();
```

As variable of the class and do

```
Collections.sort(myList, (o1, o2) -> {
  if(o1.getUtcEpoch() > o2.getUtcEpoch()) {
      return -1; //reverse order
  }    
  else if(o1.getUtcEpoch < o2.o1.getUtcEpoch) {  
      return 1; //reverse order
  }  
  return 0;
} );
```

And the `getUtcEpoch()` is

```
long getUtcEpoch() {  
   return utcMillis;
}
```

So my question is, should I stick to Date classes for sorting or using UTC millis is a better alternative?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: `org.joda.time.DateTime`

Comment: Because a [Joda time `DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is an immutable class, you only need to create such an object once and can securely return that in the getter. Just store it in an instance field. And then - of course - you can continue to use the `DateTime` object for comparing.

Comment: If the UTC milliseconds is available it's certainly much faster using that one for the comparison instead of parsing a string and creating a new object.

Comment: You could just sort by the string itself, assuming years are between `0000` and `9999`, inclusive, and time zones are all the same. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles): *"Date and time values are ordered from the largest to smallest unit of time: year, month (or week), day, hour, minute, second, and fraction of second. The lexicographical order of the representation thus corresponds to chronological order, except for date representations involving negative years. This allows dates to be naturally sorted by, for example, file systems."*

Comment: @RobertKock: It is not available but I could add it if that is optimal for comparison

Comment: @Andreas: That seems error prone to me. If it was that simple why are there so many methods to compare/before/after etc?